# MongoDB: Is it possible to create an Atlas Search index for a subset of documents?

Tags: mongodb, lucene, mongodb-atlas

I have created an Atlas Search Index which includes this `embeddedDocument` field:

```
  "customers": {
    "fields": {
      "name": {
        "name": "lucene.keyword",
        "searchAnalyzer": "lucene.keyword",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "created_at": {
        "type": "date"
      }
    },
    "type": "embeddedDocuments"
  }
```

Problem is that I have billions of entries thus getting the Lucene limit warming:

> Atlas Search: Max Number of Lucene Docs has gone above 1 billion

Sharding is not an option due to cost. Schema structure also cannot change.

I realised that I could search only for last year's customers though.

Would it be possible to index my customers based on their `created_at` date, thus reducing the index size?

Or anything similar? Thanks.